# Changing a Beamer template style

Tags: beamer

I'm using the following Beamer template which I found on the webpage:

http://recherche.noiraudes.net/en/LaTeX.php

(i.e., the style files `beamercolorthemeprogressbar`, `beamerfontthemeprogressbar`, `beamerinnerthemeprogressbar`, `beamerouterthemeprogressbar`, and `beamerthemeprogressbar`). I would like to remove the round box in "Chapter 1" of the second (and the next ones) slides and replaced it by left transparent top heading "Chapter 1" (without round box) which appears on the first slide. How can I do it? The main file is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usetheme{progressbar}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  %\usecolortheme{crane}

}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\title[]{Title}

\author{\parbox[t]{10.0cm}{\vfill \hfill\hbox{}{\bf Chapter 1} \hfill\hbox{} \vfill}}

\date{{\footnotesize Author}}

\begin{document}

% Slide 1

\begin{frame}

\maketitle

\end{frame}

% Slide 2

\begin{frame}

\section[Chapter 1]{Chapter}

\subsection[My section]{My section}

\textbf{Section.} \\
This is my section.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks. Find below screenshots
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and mark what box you'd like to remove? I don't seem to get any boxes with your code https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXG8I.png

Comment: Yes, I updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: You should specify in your post that your are using an old version of the theme

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the line `\draw[rounded corners=3pt, draw=structure.fg!80!bg] (-0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, 0pt) rectangle (0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, \progressbar@sectionboxheight);` to remove the boarder:

```
\documentclass[10pt,unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usetheme{progressbar}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  %\usecolortheme{crane}

}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\title[]{Title}

\author{\parbox[t]{10.0cm}{\vfill \hfill\hbox{}{\bf Chapter 1} \hfill\hbox{} \vfill}}

\date{{\footnotesize Author}}


\makeatletter
\usesectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill
    \setbox\progressbar@sectionbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
    \progressbar@sectionboxwidth=\wd\progressbar@sectionbox
    \advance\progressbar@sectionboxwidth by 4pt
    \setbox\progressbar@sectionbox=\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture t \endpgfinterruptpicture}%
    \progressbar@sectionboxheight=\ht\progressbar@sectionbox
    \advance\progressbar@sectionboxheight by 4pt
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, 0pt) rectangle (0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, \progressbar@sectionboxheight);
      \draw[anchor=base] (0pt, 2pt) node {\color{structure.fg!80!bg} \insertsectionhead};
%      \draw[rounded corners=3pt, draw=structure.fg!80!bg] (-0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, 0pt) rectangle (0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, \progressbar@sectionboxheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {\hfill
    \setbox\progressbar@sectionbox=\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture\insertsectionhead\endpgfinterruptpicture}%
    \progressbar@sectionboxwidth=\wd\progressbar@sectionbox
    \advance\progressbar@sectionboxwidth by 4pt
    \setbox\progressbar@sectionboxbox=\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture t \endpgfinterruptpicture}%
    \progressbar@sectionboxheight=\ht\progressbar@sectionboxbox
    \advance\progressbar@sectionboxheight by 4pt
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, 0pt) rectangle (0.5\progressbar@sectionboxwidth, \progressbar@sectionboxheight);
      \draw[anchor=base] (0pt, 2pt) node {\color{structure.fg!50!bg} \insertsectionhead};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Slide 1

\begin{frame}

\maketitle

\end{frame}

% Slide 2

\begin{frame}

\section[Chapter 1]{Chapter}

\subsection[My section]{My section}

\textbf{Section.} \\
This is my section.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]